# Prove a monomial is admissible

Tags: algebraic-topology

Set $\mathcal{F}_k\subset P_{k-1}$, where
$$\mathcal{F}_k = \{x_j^2x_{j_1}x_{j_2}\ldots x_{j_{k-3}}: 1\leqslant j_1 < j_2 < \ldots < j_{k-3}<k, \ 1 \leqslant j <k\}$$

Show that, let $z$ be a monomial in $P_{k-1}$. If $z \in \mathcal{F}_k$, then $z$ is admissible?

> $P_k :=\mathbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k]$ for the polynomial algebra over the prime field of two element, $\mathbb F_2$, in $k$ variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$, each of degree $1$. The *hit problem*, set up by F. Peterson, of finding a minimal set of generators for $P_k$ as a module over the mod-2 Steenrod algebra, $\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $j <j_1$ then $z$ is inadmissible for $z \in F_k$.
2. If $j>j_1$ then $z$ is admissible for $z\in F_k$